# Error deserializing JSON response with custom Gson deserializer

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2, json-deserialization

In my Android app using Retrofit, I am trying to deserialize JSON that has an outer object wrapping a list of items. I am using the GsonConverterFactory with the Retrofit instance to deserialize JSON. I created a custom deserializer to extract only the list of items from the response so I don't have to create the parent wrapper class. I've done this previously with Java but I am not able to get it working with Kotlin. When calling the ItemsService to getItems, I am getting the following exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Is there an issue with my deserializer or how I am configuring it with Gson and Retrofit? Is there something else I am doing wrong?

JSON:

```
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "id" : "item1"
        },
        {
            "id" : "item2"
        },
        {
            "id" : "item3"
        }
}
```

Deserializer:

```
class ItemsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<Item>> {

    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): List<Item> {

        val items: JsonElement = json!!.asJsonObject.get("items")
        val listType= object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type

        return Gson().fromJson(items, listType)
    }
}
```

Item:

```
data class Item (val id: String)
```

ItemsService:

```
interface ItemsService {

    @GET("items")
    suspend fun getItems(): List<Item>
}
```

ServiceFactory:

```
object ServiceFactory {

    private const val BASE_URL = "https://some.api.com"

    private val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type, ItemsDeserializer())
        .create()

    fun retrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()

    val itemsService: ItemsService = retrofit().create(ItemsService::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, it's a very common mistake. You have to create parameterized types with `TypeToken.getParameterized`. So you have to change `object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type` to `TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, Item::class.java).type`

```
class ItemsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<Item>> {

    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): List<Item> {

        val items: JsonElement = json!!.asJsonObject.get("items")
        val listType= TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, Item::class.java).type

        return Gson().fromJson(items, listType)
    }
}
```

```
private val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, Item::class.java).type, ItemsDeserializer())
        .create()
```