# Type adapter warning when registering java.util.List

Tags: kotlin, gson

When trying to register a type adapter, where list is java.util.List

```
GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(object : TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.type, MyObjectsTypeAdapter())
```

I get the following warning:

> This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.collections.List or
> kotlin.collections

My type adapter uses a kotlin.collections.list.

```
class MyObjectsTypeAdapter: TypeAdapter<List<MyObject>>() {
 ... 
}
```

However if I don't use java.util.List in my type adapter, gson does not match the type correctly.

Am I doing something else wrong when registering my type adapter?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case a bit? It is rarely necessary to register a type adapter for a parameterized type, and it most likely won't work the way you expect it to work because for serialization the runtime type might be used (e.g. `ArrayList`) which differs from `List<MyObject>`. Why don't you only register a type adapter for `MyObject`?

Comment: @Marcono1234 I cannot just register a type adapter for my object as my remote repository return an array of objects.  So in my case my TypeAdapter creates and returns a list of object.  I have added an example of my TypeAdapter to the question.

Comment: Normally you would create an adapter for `MyObject` and then call `gson.fromJson(..., new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType())`. That is not possible is your use case?

Comment: Nope I am not calling that manually, I am using retrofit.  Retrofit does this under the hood.

Comment: Even if you did TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType()), i'd bet "List" would have to be a java.util.List not a kotlin list.  Meaning you would get the same warning right?

Comment: If you specify the result or parameter type for Retrofit as `List<MyObject>`, then I think it should suffice to register the adapter only for `MyObject`. Gson will handle the `List` serialization and deserialization on its own. It appears using Kotlin's `List` here should be fine because it is a [mapped type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types) (though I am not completely sure). Have you tried registering only an adapter for `MyObject` yet?

Comment: I cannot get this to work.  If you have a working example that you can point me to that would be helpful.

Comment: @lostintranslation check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61969558/5595925)

Comment: @ch13mob that is the same thing I am doing.  You would still get a warning about using a Java class in Koltin.

Answer (score 0):

Below is small demo showing Retrofit usage with Gson. A few important points:

- To use Gson as converter you have to add the `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson` dependency and add the converter factory with `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`; see [Retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration)
- The custom `TypeAdapterFactory` in the example below is not needed; it just shows how you could customize the `Gson` instance

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.*
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import com.google.gson.stream.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

data class MyObject(
    val message: String
)

interface DemoService {
    @GET("demo")
    fun demo(): Call<List<MyObject>>
}

fun main() {
    val port = 8080
    // Start a demo server returning the JSON response
    embeddedServer(Netty, port) {
        routing {
            get("/demo") {
                call.respondText("[{\"message\":\"Hello from server\"}]")
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = false)

    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(object: TypeAdapterFactory {
            override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
                if (type.rawType != MyObject::class.java) {
                    return null
                }

                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") // safe due to type check at beginning
                val delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type) as TypeAdapter<MyObject>

                val adapter = object: TypeAdapter<MyObject>() {
                    override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: MyObject?) {
                        return delegate.write(writer, value)
                    }

                    override fun read(reader: JsonReader): MyObject? {
                        val value: MyObject? = delegate.read(reader)
                        return value?.copy(message = "custom-prefix: ${value.message}")
                    }
                }
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") // safe due to type check at beginning
                return adapter as TypeAdapter<T>
            }
        })
        .create()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:$port/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(DemoService::class.java)
    val response = service.demo().execute()
    println(response.body())
}
```

The following dependencies were used:

```
// For demo server
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.0")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:2.1.0")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.1.0")

implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1")
```